# Conversion to `const Y` not applicable for `R&&` on clang

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang, move-semantics

The following code compiles fine with `g++ (GCC) 4.7.1 20120721`, but
fails with a recently build `clang version 3.2 (trunk)`.

```
struct Y {};

struct X {
  operator const Y() const { return Y(); }
};

void f(Y&& y) {}

int main()
{
  f(X());
  return 0;
}
```

Changing the conversion operator to `operator Y() const` is sufficient
to make the code compile on both compilers.

Which compiler is actually standard compliant in this case? What does
the standard actually say about this?

The verbatim error as requested:

```
bla.cpp:14:5: error: no viable conversion from 'X' to 'Y'
  f(X());
    ^~~
bla.cpp:1:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'X' to
      'const Y &' for 1st argument
struct Y {
       ^
bla.cpp:1:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'X' to
      'Y &&' for 1st argument
struct Y {
       ^
bla.cpp:6:3: note: candidate function
  operator const Y() const { return Y(); }
  ^
bla.cpp:10:12: note: passing argument to parameter 'y' here
void f(Y&& y) {}
       ^
```

**EDIT:** Unfortunately even adding the overload

```
void f(const Y&) {}
```

still makes clang choose the rvalue reference overload and so this
breaks existing code that used to compile fine, e.g. with standard
containers.

Comment: Does it really say "`R&&`"? Can you post the diagnostic verbatim?

Comment: For the record, as a total guess, I'd say clang is right here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dumped the diagnostic. The problem is that it doesn't state `why` the conversion operator is not applicable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because it shouldn't convert lvalue (const Y) to rvalue (Y&&)?

Comment: @BЈовић: Yeah, but my rvalue-ref fu is not sufficient to make any more than a wild intuitive guess

Comment: @BЈовић But that leaves me with the question how to write that kind of code: returning `const Y()` was useful in C++03 to prevent calling of non-const members on the return value and AFAIK I cannot have an `operator Y&&`.

Comment: On one hand, you say you don't want to use non-const members on that object (returning `const Y`); on the other hand, you say you do (asking for a `Y&&`). There is something inconsistent here.

Comment: It seems fairly clear. A temporary of type `Y const` cannot bind to a reference of type `Y &&`. It *could* bind to a `Y const &&`, but that'd be fairly useless.

Comment: @pmr "returning `const Y()` was useful in C++03 to prevent calling of non-const members on the return value" -- and now, with rvalue references, calling non-const members on the return value makes sense, so you should no longer prevent it.

Comment: @hvd I perfectly agree with you. I still expect my legacy code to work without touching it.

Comment: @pmr About your edit, the behaviour you see in your original question makes perfect sense, the behaviour you see in your update doesn't (to me), and it doesn't work like that on my system. `struct S {}; const S f(); char g(S &&); short g(const S &); int main() { return sizeof(g(f())) != sizeof(short); }` returns 0 for me, indicating the `g(const S &)` overload is picked. Does it return 1 for you?

Comment: @hvd No it fails to compile. That is how I was made aware of it. I can reproduce this on Apple clang 4.1 and clang 3.2 trunk. This has been reported to the clang bugtracker.

Comment: @pmr Ah, right, `f()` must of course be a valid argument for `g()` in order to get `g(f())` to compile, even when it's only part of `sizeof`. I cannot say for sure whether the code is valid C++, but if it's invalid, I agree with you that this is a surprising and seemingly unnecessary source of incompatibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe clang is right to reject this. Passing the argument to `f(Y&&)` requires two conversion steps, the first being your `operator const Y()` and the second being `Y`'s copy constructor. Both count as user-defined conversions, I think, and both are implicit, which violates the principle that an implicit conversion sequence only includes one user-defined conversion.

This [Purpose of returning by const value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) contains some interesting insights into the semantics of returning a `const T`.

Hm, if I try adding an overload `void f(const Y&y)` as the edited question now does, clang behaves pretty strangly. It still complains about being unable to convert `X` to `Y`, and doesn't even list the overload `f(const Y& y)` in its diagnostic. But once I change the overload to take `Y` by value, i.e. write `void f(const Y y)`, it complains about the call to `f` being ambiguous.

This is with XCode 4.5's clang which reports `Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`. If you can reproduce this with a vanilla clang, you should probably report this on the clang mailing list - sure seems to there's a bug lurking there *somewhere*...

Comment: I think the part about the two conversions is spot on.

Comment: I have amended the question, which makes the whole problem even more difficult.

Comment: I also cannot imagine that this should be right. This would trigger a regression in pretty much every similar code that uses STL containers.

Answer (score 2):

The example is ill-formed.

Some N3242 quotes.

8.5.3 paragraph 4:

> Given types “*cv1* `T1`” and “*cv2* `T2`,” “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-related to “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is the same type as `T2`, or `T1` is a base class of `T2`. “*cv1* `T1`” is reference-compatible with “*cv2* `T2`” if `T1` is reference-related to `T2` and *cv1* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*.

paragraph 5 (bullet labels are mine):

> A reference to type "*cv1* `T1`" is initialized by an expression of type "*cv2* `T2`" as follows:
>
> 1. If the reference is an lvalue reference and ...
> 2. Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type (i.e. *cv1* shall be `const`), or the reference shall be an rvalue reference.
>
>    a. If the initializer expression
>
>    - i. is an xvalue, class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv2* `T2`", or
>    - ii. has a class type (i.e. `T2` is a class type), where `T1` is not reference-related to `T2`, and can be implicitly converted to an xvalue, class prvalue, or function lvalue of type "*cv3* `T3`", where "*cv1* `T1`" is reference-compatible with "*cv3* `T3`",
>    - then the reference is bound to ....
>
>    b. Otherwise, a temporary of type "*cv1* `T1`" is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference copy-initialization (8.5).  The reference is then bound to the temporary.  If `T1` is reference-related to `T2`, *cv1* shall be the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv2*.  ...

For the function parameter initialization, `T1` is `Y`, `T2` is `X`, and *cv1* and *cv2* are both empty.  1 is out: the reference is an rvalue reference, not lvalue reference.  2.a.i. is out: `X` is not reference-compatible with `Y`.  2.b. is out because copy-initializing an `Y` from a prvalue of type `X` involves two user-defined conversions: the conversion function and then the copy constructor of `Y`.  (The exact prohibition is in 13.3.3.1p4.)

For case 2.a.ii., the obvious choice for "*cv3* `T3`" is `const Y`, but that's no good because `Y` is not reference-compatible with `const Y`.  You might argue for trying `T3` is `Y` and *cv3* is empty, but then you're back to needing the copy constructor of `Y` as the second implicit user-defined conversion.

Comment: Are you also considering the case with two overloads? It is not really related as to why the example is ill-formed, but it would solve the real issue.