# unique_ptr ownership error when return unique_ptr from function

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm new to unique_ptr. Everything was going fine until I came across a function returning a new unique_ptr. The compiler seems to complain about more than one object potentially owning the unique_ptr. I'm not sure how to satisfy the compilers complaint. Any help is appreciated.

```cpp
void Bar::Boo()
{
    ...
    // m_Goals is of type std::unique_ptr<Goals>
    auto x = m_Goals->Foo(); // error: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
    //auto x = std::move( m_Goals->Foo() ); // same error
    ...
}


const std::unique_ptr<Goals> Goals::Foo()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Goals> newGoals( new Goals() );
    ...
    return newGoals;
    // also tried "return std::move( newGoals )" based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316727/returning-unique-ptr-from-functions
} // this function compiles
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove the `const`, the compiler is forced to use the copy constructor when you return by `const` value. There is almost no point in returning by `const` value and is strongly recommended against. Please see [Purpose of returning by const value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value) for more information.