# Should post increment operator overloading in c++ return const data type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For basic data type like int following code snippets give compilation error

```
i++ = 2;
```

So clearly `i++` is not lvalue

But when overloading a custom class in c++ most people suggest that the signature of post increment operator should be like

```
Date Date::operator++(int) {
    Date temp = *this;
    // do increment
    return temp;
}
```

My question is why shouldn't the return type be `const Date` instead of `Date` just like primitive type.

Comment: Returning a const value inhibits move semantics, for one.

Comment: @chris: That's really the only reason, but it's more than sufficient.  Are you doing that thing again where you post answers as comments?

Comment: The "primitive type" `int` doesn't turn into a `const int` by the expression `i++`. The expression `i++` just has different value category than the name (id-expression) `i`, namely `i++` is (results in) a prvalue, whereas `i` is an lvalue.

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value).