# What are the differences in the types of usage of const keyword in function header/prototype?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the various usages of the **const** keyword in the function header/prototype?

```
    const int function(const int x) const;
```

**Answer:**

The 1st const is to return by constant value [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value).

The 2nd const is to have a constant function parameter [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters).

The 3rd const is used when the function is a class method/function that should only perform some sort of query operation such as get, hence should not change any of the class attributes/data variables [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration).

Comment: Read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282).

Comment: More like read an old book. This is stale syntax  from an old standard.

Comment: Don't do that (exception speciation).

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> const E& top() const throw(StackEmpty);
> ```

`const E&` is the return type of the function `top()`. It is a reference to a constant `E`.

The `const` after the name of the function specifies, that the function won't modify the instance it is called upon and thus can be called on `const`-qualified instanced of the `struct`/`class`, `top()` is a member of.

The `throw()`-specification tells, that `top()` may throw an object of type `StackEmpty`. AFAIK such `throw()`-specifications naming a specific type are depreciated since C++11.

Comment: Sidebar: Some good reading on why throw specifications were removed from the language: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm