# Cannot return by const value from lambda

Tags: c++

I'm trying to construct a lambda that returns by `const int`, but the `const` qualifier is being discarded. In the following code, `lam1` and `lam3` are behaving as expected, but `lam2` is not. Expected output is `0 1 1` but I get `0 0 1`.

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int C{0};
  auto lam1 = [&]()->       int& {return C;};
  auto lam2 = [&]()-> const int  {return C;};
  auto lam3 = [&]()-> const int& {return C;};

  cout << is_const<remove_reference<decltype(lam1())>::type>::value << endl;
  cout << is_const<remove_reference<decltype(lam2())>::type>::value << endl;
  cout << is_const<remove_reference<decltype(lam3())>::type>::value << endl;
}
```

demo link: https://godbolt.org/z/xP4lYs

Comment: clang gives me this warning _"warning: 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect [-Wignored-qualifiers]"_

Comment: Returning by const value is pointless.  It is exactly the same as returning by value.

Comment: @NathanOliver it is for primitives, but has utility for general types. I chose int here just for simplicity.

Comment: @roro - Then you should have tried with a class type too then, the const would not have been discarded there.

Comment: simplicitly is not always clarity ;) This would be the only instance of `const` making any difference for primitives, so why would it matter... why dont you use a `struct foo {}` for the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's intended. Remember that `decltype` returns the type of an expression, possibly with a reference qualifier to match the expression's value category. `lam2` returns a prvalue, and well...

> **[expr]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6) If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T”, where T is a
>   cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
>   is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

There are no const prvalues of primitive type. Since you return a `const int`, and that's the type of the function call expression, the const is removed prior to further analysis (including `decltype` deducing the type of the expression).

For class types, that is not the case, because the cv-qualifiers can affect a class object's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that [it works this way for normal functions too](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cce022b6871a6fb3).

That's by design, because [returning built-ins by `const` value is pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8716353/560648).

However, it is the `decltype` that is "removing" it (or, rather, allowing you to observe that it's removed when used in an expression) — the `const` *is* still part of the function's signature. If your example related to a class type rather than `int`, you might have observed something else (see previous link). :)