# why the const in c++ conversion operator is meaningless?

Tags: c++, constants, overloading

In "C++ Primer", exercise 14.47, there is a question:

> Explain the difference between these two conversion
> operators:
>
> ```cpp
> struct Integral {
>     operator const int();
>     operator int() const;
> }
> ```

I don't know why the the answer I found on GitHub says that the first `const` is meaningless, because for one conversion operator should not define return type, this `const` here is unspecified, it will be ignored by the compiler. But I also found some guys say that it means the function will return a `const` value.

So, I wonder which one is correct, and why?

Comment: `const` only affects objects: It says the value of an object will not be changed through this type. An object is memory that can be changed to represent different values, so `const` says no such changes will be made using this `const` type. A value is just a single value, not memory that can change. If, in `x * y * z`, `x` is 3 and `y` is 5, then `x * y` is 15, and there is no way that some other value could be stored in `x * y`; `x * y` does not designate any memory that can change. So a `const int` value and an `int` value are the same thing, just a value.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Purpose of returning by const value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716330/purpose-of-returning-by-const-value), although I'm not 100% sure how this translates to conversion operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it will be ignored by compiler.

This is because of [expr#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6) which states:

> If a prvalue initially has the type `cv T`, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the **type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.**

This means that in your particular example, `const int` will be adjusted to `int` before further analysis since `int` is a built in type and not a class type.

> which one is right?

Even though the return type of the first conversion function is `const int`, it will be adjusted to `int` prior to any further analysis.

---

While the `const` on the second conversion function means that the `this` pointer inside that function is of type `const Integral*`. This means that it(the conversion function) can be used with `const` as well as non-const `Integral` object. This is from [class.this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.this#1)

> If the member function is declared const, the type of this is const X*, ...