# Returning a const pointer to a const data member and the 'auto' keyword. A bit confused

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, constants, auto

I've recently been learning C++ and just today have been introduced to *const* and the concept of const correctness. In an attempt to better understand the theory, I've been writing a series of simple programs to make sure that I understand the concept correctly. I thought I understood everything, but then when using the *auto* keyword in one of the programs, I seem to have got a bit stuck.

In order to test that I understood how const pointers work I wrote a simple program. I won't bother posting the whole thing since there's only two parts of it that are relevant. I have a class with a const data member of type int:

```cpp
const int tryToChangeMe;
```

Within this class I also have a member function that returns a const pointer to the above const int:

```cpp
const int* const MyClass::test()
{
    return &tryToChangeMe;
}
```

In my main function I then call the above function, making use of the *auto* keyword. In order to test that what I think I know about *const* is correct I then attempt to reassign the *tryToChangeMe* variable through the pointer. Like so:

```cpp
auto temp = myClass.test();
*temp = 100;
```

As I expected, the program wouldn't compile due to the error that I caused when trying to assign a value to a *const* variable. However, I didn't just return a pointer to *const*, I returned a *const* pointer to a *const* (at least that's what I thought I did). So to test this, I attempted to reassign the pointer to a new memory address, quite confident that I'd get a similar compilation error:

```cpp
temp = new int;
```

But quite confusingly the program compiled without any issue. Stepping through with the debugger revealed that sure enough, the pointer was losing its original address and being assigned a brand new one. Wondering what was going on, I just happened by chance to remove the *auto* keyword and replace it with the variable's full type:

```cpp
const int* const temp = myClass.test();
```

Upon testing everything again, the results were as expected and this time I was not able to reassign the pointer to a new address.

So after all that I guess my question is, why? Why does the *auto* keyword allow you to bypass the *const* qualifier of pointers? Did I do something wrong?

By the way, I'm not sure if it matters but I'm using Visual Studio 2015 preview

Comment: This article by Herb Sutter might help you understand: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/07/gotw-92-solution-auto-variables-part-1/

Comment: Thank you. Now that I know about top-level const, things are becoming more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already mentioned, `auto` ignores top level cv-qualifiers. Read [this article](http://thbecker.net/articles/auto_and_decltype/section_01.html) to learn the details of how `auto` and `decltype` work.

Now, even if `auto` didn't ignore the `const`, in your case, `temp` would still not be `const` because top level cv-qualifiers on return types are [ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051274/241631) if the type being returned is of non-class type.

g++ even produces the following warning with `-Wextra`

> warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]

This can be demonstrated by using C++14's `decltype(auto)`. Unlike `auto`, `decltype(auto)` doesn't discard references and top level cv-qualifiers. If you modify your example by adding the following lines the code will still compile, proving that `temp` is not a `const` pointer.

```
decltype(auto) temp = myClass.test();
static_assert(std::is_same<const int*, decltype(temp)>{}, "");
```

On the other hand, if `test()` returns an object of class type with a top level cv-qualifier, then `auto` would still discard `const`, but `decltype(auto)` wouldn't.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c74a5e3d5de7c76a)

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `auto` variables are not by default `const`. The fact that you return `const` value does not mean it has to be assigned to a `const` variable; the value is *copied* after all (eventhough the value is a pointer). You can try it easily with explicit type specification as well. The value stored in `myClass` won't be changed when changing the variable `temp` and the pointer target is still `const` so constness is still honored.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, does that mean that returning a const pointer is essentially pointless? (no pun intended)

Comment: @Pete if you want a `const` pointer, then declare it with `const auto`

Comment: @Pete See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299967/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5689384/4538344)

Comment: @vsoftco Yeah I understand that now. But if the constness is still honoured without the const auto, then there's no real need. Correct?

Comment: @Pete the issue is that `const`-ness is not honoured by `auto`, it is discarded when doing `auto temp`. The cv-qualifiers **are not discarded** whenever you do `auto& temp`. In this latter case, the compiler does pattern matching.

Comment: @vsoftco Copying a `const` value does not violate constness. I think you meant that constness is not *retained*.

Comment: @StenSoft yes, sorry for the sloppy language. What I meant was that the `const`-ness of the pointer is not honoured. The data it points to remains `const` indeed. A typedef will help the most here.

Comment: @vsoftco The constness is still honored, no `const` value can be changed (not event the one returned from the function; its copy stored in `temp` is no longer `const`). Honoring means the program does not break the rules of [const correctness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_%28computer_programming%29#Loopholes_to_const-correctness), retaining means the qualifiers are kept the same.

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```
auto temp = rhs;
```

type deduction works as follows:

- if `rhs` is a reference, then the reference is ignored
- the *top-level cv(const-volatile)-qualifiers* of `rhs` are also ignored (they are not ignored however if you do `auto& temp = rhs;`; in this case the compiler pattern-matches the type)

In your case, the type of the right hand side is

```
const int* const
           ^^^^^
           top-level cv qualifier
```

i.e. `const` pointer to `const`-`int`. The pointer is like any other variable, so it's `const`-ness will be discarded (technically, the top-level cv qualifier is `const` and it is discarded), hence you end up with the type of `temp` being deduced as

```
const int*
```

i.e. a non-`const` pointer to `const`-`int`, so it can be re-assigned. If you want to enforce the `const`-ness, then you have to declare the left hand side as

```
const auto temp = myClass.test();
^^^^^
need this
```

Scott Meyers has an [excellent introduction](http://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf) to the subject (also available on his [*Effective Modern C++*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996) book, Items 1 and 2 free to browse [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html#understand_template_type_deduction)), in which he explains how `template` type deduction works. Once you understand that, understanding `auto` is a breeze, since really `auto` type deduction mimic very closely the template type deduction system (with the notable exception of `std::initializer_list<>`).

**EDIT**

There is an additional rule for

```
auto&& temp = rhs;
```

but to understand it you need to understand [how forwarding (universal) references work and how reference collapsing works](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Answer (score 3):

I'll provide some formal explanation from the Standard for that fact for standard-reference-searchers.:

The section `N4296::7.1.6.4/7 [dcl.spec.auto]`

> If the placeholder is the auto type-specifier, the deduced type is
>   determined using the rules for template argument deduction.

Now, the template argument dedcution `N4296::14.8.2/3 [temp.deduct]`:

> [...] the function parameter type adjustments described in 8.3.5 are
>   performed.

And finally `N4296::8.3.5/5 [dcl.fct]`

> After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type
>   “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to
>   T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively. After producing
>   the list of parameter types, ***any top-level cv-qualifiers modifying
>   a parameter type are deleted when forming the function type***.

In short, yes, CV-qualifiers are just ignored in that case.